# ¿Cómo cargar una variable al hacer clic en un hipervínculo dentro de una misma página?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

Estoy haciendo un diseño básico, tengo una variable id que me carga un dato, para luego mostrar según ese valor información en una tabla, pero no sé cómo ponerlo dinámico, que cambie según un clic.

```
<?php                       
  $sql_sucursales="SELECT * from sucursal where deleted = 0";
  $result_sucursales=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_sucursales);   
  $id_suc=0;
  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result_sucursales))
  {

  echo '<br><p><a href="#site">',$mostrar['name'],$id_suc=$mostrar['id'],'</a> </p></br>';                  
  }
   echo '<br><p><a href="#site">Todas</a></p></br>';
?>
```

la variable llega aquí, y dependiendo del dato muestra un valor.

```
<?php                       

if(isset($id_suc))
{   
    
    $sql_name_suc="SELECT * from b13_sucursales where deleted = 0 and id = '".$id_suc."'; ";
    $result_name_suc= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_name_suc);
    while ($fila =mysqli_fetch_array($result_name_suc))
    {
        echo '<center><h1>Infome de la Sucursal:', $fila['name'],'</h1></center>';
    }               
}

?>
```

No logro que funcione, quiero que al darle clic al enlace, el valor de la variable cambie, así poder mostrar otra información, que vaya cambiando según donde de clic.

No sé si sea posible solo con PHP y HTML.

Mil gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score -1):

Si puedes hacerlo, autocarga la pagina en el enlace href='mipagina.php?variable1=valor1'.
Esto en el HTML
en el código PHP pregunats si existe la variable$_GET['variable1'] y procedes a realizar la query que deseas...

El desarrollo Web hoy día se hace de manera asíncrona.

Esta forma de trabajar ya no se usa...

Comment: Efectivamente, tenía un error al usar el concepto.